# Get different results from Pulp and Linprog

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, pulp

I am new to linear programming and trying both Pulp and (SciPy) Linprog. Each gives me different results.

I think it might be because Linprog is using interior-point method whereas Pulp is probably using simplex? If so, is there a way to get Pulp produce the same result is Linprog?

```
import pulp
from pulp import *
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# Pulp

# Upper bounds
r = {1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 7, 4: 11, 5: 7}

# Create the model
model = LpProblem(name="small-problem", sense=LpMaximize)

# Define the decision variables
x = {i: LpVariable(name=f"x{i}", lowBound=0, upBound=r[i]) for i in range(1, 6)}

# Add constraints
model += (lpSum(x.values()) <= 35, "headroom")

# Set the objective
model += lpSum([7 * x[1], 7 * x[2], 11 * x[3], 7 * x[4], 11 * x[5]])

# Solve the optimization problem
status = model.solve()

# Get the results
print(f"status: {model.status}, {LpStatus[model.status]}")
print(f"objective: {model.objective.value()}")

for var in x.values():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")

for name, constraint in model.constraints.items():
    print(f"{name}: {constraint.value()}")

# linprog

c = [-7, -7, -11, -7, -11]
bounds = [(0, 11), (0, 11), (0, 7), (0, 11), (0, 7)]
A_ub = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
B_ub = [[35]]
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=B_ub, bounds=bounds)
print(res)
```

Output from code above:

```
status: 1, Optimal
objective: 301.0
x1: 10.0
x2: 0.0
x3: 7.0
x4: 11.0
x5: 7.0
headroom: 0.0
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: -300.9999999581466
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([4.60956784e-09])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([7., 7., 7., 7., 7.])
```

Bonus question: How would I formulate a problem where I want to maximum values for x[i]'s given some constraints? Above I am trying to maximise sum of x[i]'s but wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Same objective function value. (You should be able to explain the difference in sign ). Note that not all LPs have a unique optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Erwin Kalvelagen has already pointed out in the comments not all LPs have a unique solution. In your case you have two groups of variables `{x1, x2, x4}` and `{x3, x5}` that have the same coefficients in all occurrences.

In your case it is optimal to use the maximal possible value for `x3, x5` and what ever is still available towards 35 in your constraint is distributed between `x1, x2, x4` arbitrarily (as it makes no difference for the objective).

Note that your pulp solution is a [basic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_solution_(linear_programming)) while your scipy solution is not. And yes, this likely is because the two use different algorithms to solve the problem.